# Построить Концептуальное проектирование

Tags: база-данных

База данных "Междугородные автобусные перевозки"
Задано география автомобильных дорог. Некоторое множество АТП имеет парки автобусов. Подлежащим исполнению множество рейсов, имеют определенную регулярность. Рейсы движется по дорогам, делая остановки в пунктах. Известны цены и время движения автобуса определенной марки между пунктами. Автобусами управляют водители. Продажа билетов фиксируется в БД.

Comment: @Casillas1 вы забыли добавить вопрос к вашему увлекательному повествованию

Comment: вы случайно не на немецкий стартап работаете? уж больно знакомое описание))

Comment: нет конечно)

Comment: Большинство сущностей Вами перечислено. 

А что не получается?

Comment: именно реализовать

Comment: Проблемы с связями между ними?

Попробуйте порисовать диаграммы ["сущность-связь"](http://citforum.ru/database/dblearn/dblearn08.shtml).

Comment: от именно это как сделать я не знаю(